# Zynga Scroller "Completed" Method?

Tags: javascript, html, scroller

I'm using Zynga Scroller (
https://github.com/zynga/scroller) to scroll a list and snap to middle. I need something to hook onto when the scrolling is complete to show an article based on that list item. My question is there a way to use "completed" (which is in the core)?